# Not able to publish to remote Git repo through Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2017

I don't know what the best way is to setup Visual Studio and a remote Git repo and link them together. I've looked at some videos and read some articles but I'm still getting the "rejected updates because the remote contains work that you do not have locally". Here are the steps I took. Can someone tell me the step I'm missing or if there is a different way I should go about doing this?

1. Created a remote Git repo through our TFS website. This is an
   on-premise server.
2. Cloned the remote repo down to C:\TFS\Projects\RepoName.
3. Opened Visual Studio 2017 and created an new console app. I pointed the folder to the C:\TFS\Projects and name the project the
   same as the RepoName I used in cloning. I unchecked the "Create
   Folder" and "Add to Git" boxes.
4. In VS went to File | Add To Source Control.
5. Added a test file and then tried to Sync to the remote repo and get the error.

Comment: If you use the git command line to push, do you get the same error?

Comment: I get "Updates were rejected beause of the tip of your current branch is behind it's remote counterpart".

Comment: You might try running `git pull` to retrieve the latest changes, then.

Comment: I just tired "git pull origin master" and get "refusing to merge unrelated histories"

Comment: Maybe try rebasing intead: `git pull --rebase origin master`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you have done is created a new project on Remote, Cloned it on Local, then added new folder and files replaced with remote folders and then tried to add the files using VCS to source code.

There are multiple way of doing what you're doing, it seems like you are just a beginner i would suggest,

Create local repo and push that on Remote. Instead of doing other way around.

You can follow this doc to do this,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs-2017?view=azure-devops

Comment: Definitely a beginner with Git. I did most of what the article said to do except that I created the remote repo prior to linking the local repo with the remote repo. I didn't think VS would be able to create the remote repo for me but maybe it can. I'll have to test that out.

Comment: I followed the article you posted but I'm posting to an on premise TFS server and not Azure. It won't create the remote repo for me and in the description it even says to connect to an existing remote repository. However, if I create that remote repo first I'm back in the same boat with the same error message I posted.

Comment: But then there is something that is going wrong while connecting local repo with your remote. how about you check and allow to add newly added files to git which you mentioned that you unchecked it ?

Comment: That check box for Git in VS initializes the local folder to be a Git project. It doesn't look to have any effect on connecting to a remote repo. I might have found another way which is cumbersome but I'm still testing that method out.